# Mysql - group by with condition if field match choose on base of other field

Tags: mysql

My Table is

```
id name active gid
38  abc  1      2
49  cba  1      1
51  dfg  1      1
23  gst  1      2
54  dfg  1      2
58  gst  1      1
```

in a simple case i used this query

```
SELECT  id, name FROM test_table WHERE (gid = 2 OR gid = 1) and active = 1 group by name
```

But my requirement is if the table holds several records with same name, the record with gid = 2 should be in result.

if there is more than 1 record with the same name and gid=2, any random record is okay. Same thing if there is only records with gid=1 for a same name.

```
 id     name    
 38     abc
 49     cba
 23     gst
 54     dfg
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Not a solution, but an optimisation, change `WHERE (user_org.gid = 2 OR user_org.gid = 1) ` to `WHERE user_org.gid IN (1, 2)`

Comment: if you add sample of raw data and expected result it would help a lot!

Comment: Sorry for that but now edited may be this will be more clear

Comment: is this should be still on hold ?? or should i ask this as new question

Comment: for me it is still not clear @user3712320 why row id=49 is IN result, but row id=51 is not. what is criteria? sO i get it

Comment: So I think I get it you mean not 'match' but 'same' :-) if several records with the same name, you need to select that record that holds 2 in gid?

Comment: @kim Alexander  because id - 49 , name - cba is not duplicate But id - 51 name - dfg and id - 54 name - dfg, so dfg name is duplicate, i need id - 54 name - dfg because its gid is 2

Comment: so, once 'on hold" will switch to normal - you'll get several answers

Comment: and another question what should happen if there more than 1 record with the same name and gid=2 ??

Comment: @KimAlexander in that case any random record will be okay for me with gid =2

Comment: Is it possible to have more than 1 record with the same name and gid=1 ? And if yes, which one do you want to output ?

Comment: @FabienTheSolution yes that possible but in that case i just need distinct records and even if more than 2 records with gid =1 but only one record with gid =2 and all other values are duplicate then also gid =2 will be selected

Comment: When you say "I just need distinct records"...do you mean you want them all or one....let say we have `49  cba  1      1` and `64  cba  1      1`...Do you want both `49  cba` AND `64  cba` or any one of them ?

Comment: Ok...take a look at this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9022ef/4 The subquery will return 2 as GID if you have records with gid=1 and gid=2 or only records gid=2 for the same name or will return 1 as GID if you only have record(s) with gid=1 for a given name
The main `select` will output only one of them, in this case, the records with the lower ID (You can use MAX if you want to get the last ID). I will post it as answer if your question is reopen. Hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9022ef/4)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(3), `active` int, `gid` int)
;

INSERT INTO test_table
    (`id`, `name`, `active`, `gid`)
VALUES
    (38, 'abc', 1, 2),
    (49, 'cba', 1, 1),
    (51, 'dfg', 1, 1),
    (23, 'gst', 1, 2),
    (47, 'gst', 1, 2),
    (54, 'dfg', 1, 2),
    (58, 'gst', 1, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT min(id), t1.name
FROM test_table t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  name, max(gid) as gid
     FROM test_table 
     WHERE gid in (1,2) and active = 1 
     group by name) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND 
                          t1.gid = t2.gid
group by t1.name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9022ef/4/0)**:

```
| min(id) | name |
|---------|------|
|      38 |  abc |
|      49 |  cba |
|      54 |  dfg |
|      23 |  gst |
```